# error received on running virtual emulator on Android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I deleted the emulator and reinstalled it because i did not knew how to close it ,once it is opened.....
Now after reinstalling when i use
`flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>` , it gives me the following error-
The Android emulator exited with code 1 during startup
Android emulator stderr:
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): SupportPixelFold
ERROR   | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
ERROR   | is an experimental feature.
ERROR   | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.

how to fix this up in windows??

I tried find AVD manager in tools section but it was not there.

Comment: Can you change Emulated Performance Graphics option to Software and report back?